# I am passing ajax request to other remoter server for access record

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get data by passing ajax request on other remote server controller  from my current remote page

Here is my 1st remote view page code:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<script src="/assets/js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.noConflict();
</script>
     <div class="breadcrumb-row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 m-b30">
                     <div class="section-head">
                        <div class="newsLetter-bx">

                      <form role="form" id="status_form" name="status_form" method="post" autocomplete="off" >

                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input name="lr_no" id="lr_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter L.R No" type="text">
                                    <span  class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" id="get" class="site-button m-l10">Submit</button>
                                    </span> 
                                </div>
                            </form>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#get").click(function(){
           console.log("hello");
           status_form();
           return false;
          });

     function status_form()
       {
            var lr_no = $('#lr_no').val();
                     $.ajax({
                          url :"http://demo.barque.online/sitecontroller/StatusController/fetchStatus",
                          type:"POST",
                          dataType: "json",
                          data:{
                            lr_no:lr_no,
                         },
                          dataType: "html",
                          success: function(data)
                          {
                            console.log(data);
                            // $('#status_table').html(data);
                            // //$('#consignor_name').trigger("change");
                            // enquiryStatus();

                          },
                          error:function(data)
                          {
                            alert("error message"+data);
                          },async:false,
                      });    

      }
</script>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Here is my 2nd remove controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class StatusController extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!is_logged_in()) 
        {
             redirect("user/SigninController/"); 
        }else{
              $this->load->model("sitemodel/StatusModel",'sModel');
        }
     }
    function fetchStatus(){
    $lr_no            = $this->input->post('lr_no');
    $statusResult     = $this->sModel->fetchStatus($lr_no);
    echo json_encode($statusResult);
    }
   }
```

Here is my model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class StatusModel extends CI_Model {
                 function fetchStatus($lr_no){ 
                        $this->db->select('*'); 
                        $this->db->from('bilty');
                        $this->db->where('lr_no',$lr_no);           
                        $query = $this->db->get();
                         return $query->result();
                   }
                }
```

I am getting this error

```
jquery.min.js:4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://demo.barque.online/sitecontroller/StatusController/fetchStatus' from origin 'http://barquetranslogistics.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.
I am just passing id(lr_no) through ajax request from my web site page to other project controller's function

Comment: why two controller in URL ??

Comment: @DevsiOdedra `sitecontroller`(is my directory name) and `StatusController` is my controller name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have the JS hosted in `http://barquetranslogistics.com` (the origin) and the remote PHP server is hosted in `http://demo.barque.online`, you could post cross-domain from JS using this PHP headers :

```
public function __construct()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://barquetranslogistics.com');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
    parent::__construct();
    if(!is_logged_in()) 
    {
        redirect("user/SigninController/"); 
    }else{
        $this->load->model("sitemodel/StatusModel",'sModel');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It says everything in the error itself. You are facing this error because you don't have the CORS policy setup at the requested domain. A web application is not allowed to make requests outside of its domain, unless the reponse from other origin includes the right CORS headers.

You can read more about CORS policy here-

[CORS Policy Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

You can solve this problem either using [CORS anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) or by setting up the CORS headers at the other origin. Hope it helps.

[How to use CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation)